# yii2 listview next page without changing url

Tags: yii2

Yii2 listview is missing `$.fn.yiilistview.update` from yii1. Even more, it is dependent on pjax for basic requirements and thus creates all kinds of issues with nested pjax , timeouts etc for simple pagination with listView.

A GET request to controller is rendered by javascript into an HTML ( jSON returned from controller containing listview html ) . Since URL is not changed in this process, I did not use pjax for avoiding complexity and made simple ajax call and based on data returned on success will update container. ( like pjax does only manually using ajax without changing url)

now when I do next page, then URL is updated and also page full refreshes. Initially it was not working as well but once I added an IF check on page GET param inside controller and instead of returning renderAjax output in JSON, would directly return HTML now

How can we avoid updating URL with yii2 listview next page without using pjax and make it work seeemlesly with controller and javascript written in fashion to emulate pjax in manual ajax calls as stated above ?

Controller :

```
if($pageParam == null) {
    $page =  $this->renderAjax("_list", [
                        "dataProvider" => $dataProvider
             ]) ;

    Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
    return array("error"=>false,"page"=>$page);
} else {
    return $this->renderAjax("_list", [
                        "dataProvider" => $dataProvider
             ]) ;
}
```

List View :

```
<?php if($dataProvider != null) : ?>
    <?= 
    ListView::widget([
        'id'=>'itemList',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
        'itemView' => '_dataListView',
        'summary'=>'',
        'emptyText'=>$emptyPage         
    ]) 
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

js :

ajax success GET callback :

```
success     : function(data) {
                    if(!data.error) {
                        $("#list-container").html(data.page);
```

`listcontainer` itself resides in parent view for `_list`

Answer (score 8):

you can configure pjax widget like this:

```
    <? Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]) ?>
...
    <? Pjax::end() ?>
```

you might also be interested in the `'enableReplaceState'` option. [doc here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html)

Comment: I tried these in PHP . however I faced an issue here since I was returning output of renderAjax to javascript which was replacing container with this output. pjax calls were not working correctly in ajax, but with full refresh I agree doing in PHP would probably create no issues

Comment: best case would have been when I would have not need pjax at all for such a thing since URL did not need to change. but it seems yii2 has deep connection with pjax and we need to find ways around it

Comment: my latest ongoing struggle with pjax and yii listview is with pagers in listview that once implemented in way I answered (ie adding pjax using js), adding infinite scroll on top has been not working (when multiple listviews on same page - ajax based ).  i am removing pjax calls where infinite scroll is needed as it does something similar to pjax -  it needs container as well and appends in place of replacing container content.

Comment: i use this a lot and did not have any issues. in my actions, i usually return  '->render(...)' and let yii do the work. why are you ajaxing here?

Comment: most of website I am working on is ajax driven and per page , there are about three or more buttons that change state of page partially but don't change URL. With pjax I had to write controller keeping in mind all kinds of scenario like pjax timesout and then pjax can be disabled.Pjax also would abort other pjax call that by some coincidence was running in parallel. Besides these partial refreshes ( done using renderAjax) did not demand URL change, some of them are modals with dynamic content. So went with ajax and replacing container by hand. Where url change, there I use pjax

Answer (score 0):

well, figured this out, trick was to not do pjax:begin / pjax:end calls in PHP and instead take control in javscript as any way I was manually replacing HTML using JSON returned from yii.

I could not figure a way without pjax - so here is solution on ajax:success

```
$("#list-container").html(data.page);
$(document).pjax('a', '#list-container', {push:false});
```